# Can weight paint symmetry by "Mirror vertex groups" which includes several naming rule be more flexiable?

Tags: weight-painting

When I need to paint weight synnmetrically, I found I only can do so when bone's name is like "****.R" and "****.L".

But now I work on the bones which dont have that naming rule.
How can I specify new naming rule or rename those other bones name to the one with yellow line in the picture? (like "mixamorig:LeftHandPinky4" to "HandPinky4.L").

[image]

Comment: I think your best bet would be to rename the bones via script-- there should be examples of scripts doing so on this site.  If you need to retain the bones' names for animation data, you could store their original name as a custom property to restore names (via script) afterwards.

Comment: Thank you. I found "mixamo rig renamer". I didnt know there is a function to restore names.